# FrameNet WordNet mapping

Tags: mapping, wordnet

I need to map framenet lexical units to their synsets. I was wondering if there is any new and state of the art tool for that. I found two mappings:

1)  http://www.cse.unt.edu/~rada/downloads.html#verbmap

2)  http://danielepighin.net/cms/research/MapNet

The second one is newer, but unfortunately, it maps words to wordnet 1.6 which is so old.

Does anybody know a better tool. If I use the first tool, I miss some words (which don't exist in the map) and if I use the second one, the synset ID which I get are not compatible with wordnet 3.0 and I have to use another tool to convert them (which may cause some errors here). As I want to have as few errors as possible, I need to use the newest tool.

Best,